# Determine a transformation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine a transformation matrix that projects on the line $$4x-2y=6$$

My attempt:

Now the line can be rewritten: $$y=2x-3$$

So my book suggests displacing the line through the origin with this matrix:

$$ \left( \begin{matrix} 1&0&0 \\ 0&1&3 \\ 0&0&1 \end{matrix} \right) $$

Then project it on $y=2x$ and then putting it back with $$ \left( \begin{matrix} 1&0&0 \\ 0&1&-3 \\ 0&0&1 \end{matrix} \right) $$

I'm not sure how this displacement process is working. I understand how a projection works when it goes through the origin but how is it being displaced? How does my book get this displacement matrix?

This problem is using homogeneous coordinates but I don't understand how that works?

Comment: This 3x3 matrices are 3d transformations, but your equality shows a plane in 3d space, and not a line! Are you sure, that your problem weren't about 2x2 matrices?

Comment: Quite sure. They mention homogeneous coordinates though, but I never understood those.

Comment: Are you assuming $z=0$?

Comment: There is no mentio nof a $z$. This is strange..

Comment: Homogeneous coordinates use Z=1 or some non zero constant. I am not sure if that explains anything, though.

Comment: Can you explain "displacing the line through the origin"? What's the result you get after that? Also, what does "projects on the line" mean? Some examples might be better.